# How to solve Oracle 11g XE installation problems on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04

I follow this  links [link1](https://www.len.ro/work/oracle-11g-release-2-xe-on-ubuntu-12-04/comment-page-1/) and [link2](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/) to install Oracle 11g XE on Ubuntu 14.04.After Following all the steps, still it is showing following problems:

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

whenever i try to open oracle on web browser, oracle remain unable to install.

```
http://localhost:8081/apex/f?p=4950
```

BTW I have also XAMPP installed in my pc.

updates: after is installation i did this, But still oracle Not works.

```
usr@pc: cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 01-JAN-2016 13:03:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/usr-pc/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=usr_pc)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                01-JAN-2016 13:03:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/usr-pc/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=usr-pc)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ echo $http_proxy
localhost
```

please suggest me,how can i fix it.please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I give you the steps extracted from this [link](http://tuhrig.de/3-ways-of-installing-oracle-xe-11g-on-ubuntu/) chapter "Installing Oracle XE with Docker". It is the simplest way I assure you. Good luck !

1-Install Docker on your Linux machine. You can find instructions for that at http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux. But it is nothing more then this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main\
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

2-Pull the image to your machine:

```
docker pull alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
```

3-Run the image:

```
docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
```